# Algorithm for a red to green colour gradient

Tags: algorithm

I need some mathematical algorithm for converting the value from #FF0000 to #00FF00.

I do not want to go via a black value. The conversion should go from red to some cyan color (light blue) then to turn into green. If just needed to go from FF0000 to 000000 and then to 00FF00 it would be very easy.

The goal is to have levels let say from 0 to 1000 where 0 is #FF0000 and 1000 is #00FF00.
All I need is some smart mapping.

Comment: You know those are hexidecimal values, right? All you have to decide is how you want your gradient to go. You could first go down from red to black and then to green. Or you could simultaneously go down in the red component and increase the green component. Of course that would not give you 1000 levels (just 512 or 256), but it should be straight forward to do.

Comment: and how much you will pay me for doing it? ;)

Comment: that is the point I do not want to have black value, the conversion should go from red to some cyan color (light blue) then to turn in green. If just needed to do from FF0000 to 000000 and then to 00FF00 it would be very easy

Comment: So then your question is no longer a red-to-green problem. You're asking for gradients with 3 components now, where black is never an option. In any case, you might want to look up the HSV representation. RGB is not ideal for these cases. Quite a nice demonstration of this [is given here](http://www.perbang.dk/rgbgradient/).

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič I can't try anything because I do not have knowledge of this topic. All I come up is with going through the black color meaning first I decrease the red from FF to 00 the I increase the green from 00 to 00, but I want blue to be active, and passing from red to green should be soft with some kind of light blue value...

Comment: @user3106633 Then it sounds like you should simply start studying. Try to understand how various colour spaces work. Look up gradient formulas. There is plenty of information online. This is not all that great a question at the moment.

Comment: @Bart I do not want to reinvent a wheel if someone have the algorithm for the conversion I can just use it. That is the purpose of the stackoverflow -> sharing knowledge , problems, algorithms...

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel. You have to look at some of the existing information out there to understand your own problem and look at the many available solutions. Dumping code here that does "something" for you is not going to be of much help.

Comment: For small things like this it helps a lot. @Pooya give me some start up so I will continue from that snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, I understand you want to be able to show colors between red and green, and that you don't want to "go through black", which I understand as "I want to keep the same intensity".

For this to work, you need to change color spaces. Instead of RGB move to [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Take the HSL value for your red, then the HSL value for your green, and interpolate between them in HSL space.

Convert all the intermediate values back to RGB, and there you have your red to green range.

Comment: @user3106633 A while ago I wrote some HSL color interpolation code in Java. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mrzli/hellhopper/blob/master/germlibrary/src/com/turbogerm/germlibrary/util/ColorInterpolator.java). It also contains code for converting from rgb to hsl and viceversa.

Answer (score 3):

For a general solution, Bart's suggestion to use the HSV space is good. Pooya's and Emilio's answers will interpolate between red and green in the RGB space, which will yield dark yellow/olive in the middle.

If you need a gradient only between red and green, I suggest the following quick solution: Interpolate between red and yellow (`#FFFF00`) in the first half, and between yellow and green in the second half:

```
unsigned int red_green_interpol(double x)
{
    if (x <= 0.0) return 0xFF0000;
    if (x >= 1.0) return 0x00FF00;

    if (x < 0.5) {
        unsigned int g = 510 * x;

        return 0xFF0000 | g << 8;
    } else {
        unsigned int r = 510 * (1.0 - x);

        return 0x00FF00 | r << 16;
    }
}
```

I used a double between 0.0 and 1.0 instead of your integer range from 0 to 1000, but it shouldn't be difficult to adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this :

c :

```
void print_color ( int value )
{
    int r=(255*value)/1000;
    printf("#%02x%02x00",r,255-r)
}
```

### edit !

sorry , i didn't read question carefully!

to represent all three colors :

c:

```
void print_color ( int value )
{
 int curr=(3*value)/1000;
 int color[3];

 color[curr%3]=(255* (value-curr*(1000/3)))/(1000/3);
 color[(curr+1)%3]=255-color[curr];
 color[(curr+2)%3]=0;

 printf("#%02x%02x%02x",color[0],color[1],color[2]);
 }
```

(indexes can be changed for RGB orders...)

Comment: You should use the format specifier `"#%02x%02x00"`, otherwise your string will be too short near pure red or near pure green.

Comment: How dopes this goes through cyan, if no blue is ever present? This goes from red to green through dark-yellow.

Comment: To be fair @EmilioGaravaglia, that requirement was not originally stated by the OP. That was only mentioned afterwards in a comment. Not the greatest of questions.

Answer (score 0):

well already answered but you wanted something easy:

```
void gradient()
    {
    const int _a=3; // color components order
    const int _r=2;
    const int _g=1;
    const int _b=0;

    union _col  // color
        {
        DWORD dd;   // unsigned 32bit int (your color)
        BYTE db[4]; // 4 x BYTE
        } col;

    col.db[_r]=255; // start color 0x00FF0000
    col.db[_g]=  0;
    col.db[_b]=  0;
    col.db[_a]=  0;

    for (int i=0;i<255;i++) // gradient cycle (color 'intensity' = 255)
        {
        col.db[_r]--;
        col.db[_g]++;
        // here use your color col.dd;
        }
    }
```

for levels case there are only 255 levels in this case so remove for and add this instead (level=i 0..255):

```
    col.db[_r]=255-i;
    col.db[_g]=    i;
    col.db[_b]=    0;
    col.db[_a]=    0;
```